# wordpress site down, missing files php

Tags: php, wordpress

Something auto-updated over night and now my site is broken.

What does this mean?

> Warning:
>   require_once(/home/content/86/9642286/html/tapped-ch/wp-settings.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home/content/86/9642286/html/tapped-ch/wp-config.php on
>   line 89
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required '/home/content/86/9642286/html/tapped-ch/wp-settings.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in
>   /home/content/86/9642286/html/tapped-ch/wp-config.php on line 89

Comment: The error message simply means that the _wp-settings.php_ file is either missing or is not readable by the webservice user. What server environment do you have?

Comment: @dferenc its a go daddy hosted wordpress site using linux. not sure sure if thats the info you were looking for. if i download a fresh wordpress file and upload only the wp-settings.php file will that solve this or is there site specific content in the settings file?

Comment: First, do you see the files there? If so, this is about access permissions. In case you do not see the files, that is a bad sign. _wp-settings.php_ is part of the wp package and is safe to replace.

Comment: Are you sure it was an update? If it wasn't it's possible (Especially if the WordPress wasn't updated) it could have been hacked overnight